# unable to insert space between p elements in a div tag when fetching its content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Summary :**

I am running the following syntax of jQuery :

```
var value = $('#displayContent').text();
```

to count the words, but before I want to use the `RegExp` in `value` to add the last word and first word of each sentence together e.g

so if I had 3 lines the first line ending word is joined with the second line first word and pulls that as one word.

each line is in its own `<p>` tag Is there any way of running the above var to add a space to each p tag?

Any immediate help will be highly appreciable.

code I am running is

```
 var _wordCount = function () {



    var value = $('#displayContent').text();


    if (value.length == 0) {
        $('#show_word_count').html(0);

        return;
    }


    $('#show_word_count').html(wordCount);

};

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#displayContent').change(_wordCount);
    $('#displayContent').keydown(_wordCount);
    $('#displayContent').keypress(_wordCount);
    $('#displayContent').keyup(_wordCount);
    $('#displayContent').blur(_wordCount);


});
```

so the value keeps pulling the combined words

Comment: Can you please post the code that you tried so far.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data? if you need the tags, use html() instead of text().

Comment: so I am running the following for word count works ok with fullstops at the end of each sentence but for titles etc keeps adding the words together

Comment: Try by adding &nbps; after each <p>

Comment: HTML pulls back the tags which l don't want

Comment: Can you post the RegEx?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a problem with linebreaks. If you had three sentences, if the last word and then the first word and being combined as one, the problem is you need to handle the linebreak between them.

As Rohit asked, I'd recommend posting code or just troubleshooting linebreaks (**\n** or **\r\n**) to determine the problem.